# How to integrate the gmail smtp in magento2 site?

Tags: magento2, smtp

I am facing some issue with email functionality in magento2 site so need to resolve it, so anyone know solution, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Hi download magepal module for it.

Comment: Did you check, your serevr is sending forgot password mail?

Answer (score 0):

This extension from Mageplaza should be very helpful.

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-smtp/

Its free, and you could checkout from

https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-smtp

This link also provides very nice installation and configuration instructions. Basically, from configuration you need to choose one from the many SMTP providers, Gmail included of course.